# bad request error 400 with Requests library

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests

I am attempting to automate the process of passing text from a website to a tool in order the estimated reading level of the text.  However, when I pass the url-encoded text via a post method, i get error 400 bad request.

```
article = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
headers = ({'Host': 'auto-ilr.ll.mit.edu',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Referer': 'https://auto-ilr.ll.mit.edu/instant/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'})
s = requests.Session()
#s.mount('https://', SSLAdapter())
s.mount('https://', MyAdapter())
try:
    postdata = urllib.parse.urlencode({'Language': 'English', 'Text': article})
    soup = s.post('https://auto-ilr.ll.mit.edu/instant/summary3', data=postdata, headers = headers, verify=False)
```

I'm not sure what the difference is but there have been a few cases where the request has gone through and the final soup variable ended with the text from the site, but it was text showing the site did not correctly process the text i included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* missing something simple , you don't have to encode `data` ,  `requests` does it for you :

```
article = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',  
    'Referer': 'https://auto-ilr.ll.mit.edu/instant/'  
}
postdata = {'Language': 'English', 'Text': article}
s = requests.Session()
soup = s.post('https://auto-ilr.ll.mit.edu/instant/summary3', data=postdata, headers = headers, verify=False)

print(soup.status_code)
```

Also , you dont have to send all the headers , mabe just 'User-Agent' or 'Referer'  sometimes .